# Python csv input and output algorithm

Tags: python-3.x

I am building an algorithm without using a module.
My algorithm is calculate each line's value from 111.txt, which have

```
2,2,2,2
4,4,0,4
2,3,3,3
```

to 222.txt. So the result what i want is

```
Column, Sum, Mean, STD, Median, Mode, Min, Max
1,8,2,0,2,2,2,2
2,12,3,2,4,4,0,4
3,11,2.75,0.5,3,3,2,3
```

My algorithm is

```
infile = open("111.txt", "r")
outfile = open("222.txt", "w")

outfile.write("Column,Sum,Mean,STD,Median,Mode,Min,Max\n")

for line in infile:                             
    infileline = line.rstrip().split(",")
    infileline.sort()
    while line != "":
        total = float(infileline[0]) + float(infileline[1]) + float(infileline[2]) + float(infileline[3])
        mean = total / 4
        std =  ((float(infileline[0])**2 + float(infileline[1])**2 + float(infileline[2])**2 + float(infileline[3])**2) / 4) - mean**2
        median = (float(infileline[1]) + float(infileline[2])) / 2
        mode = 2
        minimum = float(infileline[0])
        maximum = float(infileline[3])
        line = infile.readline()

outfile.write("1")
outfile.write(",")
outfile.write("%1.0f" % total)
outfile.write(",")
outfile.write("%1.0f" % mean)
outfile.write(",")
outfile.write("%1.0f" % std)
outfile.write(",")
outfile.write("%1.0f" % median)
outfile.write(",")
outfile.write("%1.0f" % mode)
outfile.write(",")
outfile.write("%1.0f" % minimum)
outfile.write(",")
outfile.write("%1.0f\n" % maximum)

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

but the problem is my algorithm read only first line on the 111.txt
Therefore, the result is like this on 222.txt

```
Column,Sum,Mean,STD,Median,Mode,Min,Max
1,8,2,0,2,2,2,2
```

Also,I've been thinking a lot, but I don't know how to write the algorithm of the column and the algorithm of the mode.

Comment: thank you for the help anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You result file open on 'w' mode (rewrite file by last value), just use 'a' (append) mode.
2. Script write only last operation at the loop, you must add write block to the loop.
3. You don't need this line `line = infile.readline()`.

This code must be look like this:

```
infile = open("111.txt", "r")
outfile = open("222.txt", "a")
outfile.write("Column,Sum,Mean,STD,Median,Mode,Min,Max\n")
column = 0

for line in infile:
    if line:
        column += 1
        infileline = line.rstrip().split(",")
        infileline.sort()
        total = float(infileline[0]) + float(infileline[1]) + float(infileline[2]) + float(infileline[3])
        mean = total / 4
        std =  ((float(infileline[0])**2 + float(infileline[1])**2 + float(infileline[2])**2 + float(infileline[3])**2) / 4) - mean**2
        median = (float(infileline[1]) + float(infileline[2])) / 2
        mode = 2
        minimum = float(infileline[0])
        maximum = float(infileline[3])

        outfile.write(str(column)+',')
        outfile.write(','.join("%1.0f"%i for i in (total, mean, std, median,
                                                   mode, minimum, maximum)))
        outfile.write('\n')

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much. It work really well. I finally got the right code! I hope you have a great day!!